# Data binding in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I have a class which contain 3 strings

e.g.:

```
class abc
        {

            public string a, b, c;

            public abc(string d, string e, string f)
            {
                a = d;
                b = e;
                c = f;
            }


       };

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            abc obj = new abc("abc1","abc2","abc3");

            var MainPage1 = new MainPage();
            MainPage1.DataContext = obj;
        }
```

and when I try to bind to a textblock it doesn't bind

```
<TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="201,66,0,0" Name="textBlock1" **Text="{Binding Path=a}"** VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="201,107,0,0" Name="textBlock2" **Text="{Binding Path=b}"** VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="201,156,0,0" Name="textBlock3" **Text="{Binding Path=c}"** VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

I think I am missing something, but need help to find it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643): The data binding engine supports public properties, sub-properties, as well as indexers, of any common language runtime (CLR) object.

So use properties instead of public fields:

```
public class abc
{

   public string a { get; set; }
   public string b { get; set; }
   public string c { get; set; }

   public abc(string d, string e, string f)
   {
      a = d;
      b = e;
      c = f;
   }

}
```

Now you can set it as the `DataContext` e.g. in your MainPage's constructor:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        abc obj = new abc("abc1", "abc2", "abc3");

        this.DataContext = obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks sir, but after making it a property it still does not work?

Comment: You should check the output window in VS during runtime looking for binding errors.

Comment: am i missing some code at any point, as it does not show any binding error?

Comment: If there are no binding errors and the textblock are still empty there is something else causing the problem. It's not clear what do you want to do with `button1_Click`. When do you fire it? How do you show `MainPage1`? Are the textblocks on MainPage? Can you add this information to your post?

Comment: there are 3 textblock at a main page which are bind to a Property a,b,c. I am trying to make a object-(MainPage1) of a class             mainpage<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication8.MainPage" and trying to bind a class abc object -(obj) to a MainPage1.datacontext.

Comment: If you want to set the DataContext for the current page you need to do it in the constructor not in the button handler. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allow to bind to fields, make it properties of your class.